# gcloud component update fails

Tags: components, gcloud

I've deployed to VM's running Debian on GCE and have cron scripts that use gcloud commands.

I noticed that `gcloud components update` retuns this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation

My mac works fine to update gcloud and add new components.

The built in gcloud tools that were in the VM image won't update.  I have not found out how to enable the component manager.

Answer (score 19):

### UPDATED

Now you can use `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` command to install or update Google Cloud SDK.

You may need to add Cloud SDK repository in your Linux machine. This is the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu).

### Note: The following workaround should not be used anymore.

The component manager is enabled on latest images and `gcloud components update` command should be working now.

In case you're still experiencing this issue, use the following command to enable updater:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/true/false/' /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.json
```

Comment: This is a bad suggestion. Linux distros require package installation/uninstallation/updates to happen through their package management systems. Enabling the Cloud SDK component manager and updating will effectively change the files underneath the package manager. This will cause problems in the future when the package gets updated in the package manager, or when you try to remove it.

Comment: @Kamran not sure if I'm not looking at the latest solution. I just followed the instructions link for ubuntu, got the latest sdk installed on my VM, but still- "the component manager is disabled for this installation" when I tried to install more components

Comment: @Kamran I am experiencing the same issue, trying to setup a CI build agent on a cloud instance however I cannot install the docker component. (i have run the above fixes) You mentioned that this is fixed on the latest images on gcloud which instance images are you referring to?

Comment: This helped ==>>> Kamran: Try step no. 5 of this link ===>>> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get

Answer (score 6):

You cannot update components using the built in SDK tools on a compute engine instance. However you can download another local copy of the SDK from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/ (curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash) and update your path accordingly to use the new SDK install, and you will have the component manager enabled.

Comment: To provide some context; linux distros require package installation/uninstallation/updates to happen through their package management sytems. That is why Cloud SDK's internal components manger is disabled when installed through those package management systems.

Comment: So Google disabled it when they built the debian image and I have no way to update them to get bug fixes or new features?   this still does not make sense to disable updates.  the apt-get can not locate gcloud so it was not in a repository.    I check my os x version and I have newer components for key components like compute, gsutil, and my debian GCE instances is missing app engine component which means I can not do any GAE automation from within the GCE instance without this component.    I'm not sure your answer addresses the original question

Answer (score 4):

Came here while trying to `gcloud components install [x]` on a Docker container from `google/cloud-sdk` and getting the same error (I am probably not the only one on this situation).

Unfortunately, `apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` (as suggested on the most upvoted answer) didn't help.

But the ugly `sed` on config file did the trick. Dirty but efficient fix (for the moment).

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/"disable_updater": true,/"disable_updater": false,/' /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Vilas's explanation above: you can't run the updater for the built in gcloud image.  However you can install a copy of gcloud outside of the package manager and run the updater on that gcloud install.

Answer (score 2):

You can now run `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` on the Google Compute Engine default images to update the Cloud SDK.