# Unable to ssh into GCE docker container

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This is my first time using google cloud platform and feeling a bit lost.

I pushed my custom ubuntu image (created from a Dockerfile) to GCE and then created a container cluster from the console.

What I got is: a container cluster and a vm instances cluster.

I can ssh into these instances and see them blank, I mean it does not have what I built from the Dockerfile on my system. I copied some source code into it.
I did docker images in the whatever instance I sshed but could not see the image I pushed.

I am totally lost now. My basic question is
How do I see contents of my container or how do I ssh into it.

I tried following some tutorials but no success.
For ex: I tried this command **gcloud compute instances list** and got some big string (*gke-cluster-1-53f024ac-node-s5zc*) as instance name. When I tried this command **gcloud compute ssh gke-cluster-1-53f024ac-node-s5zc** I got error that instance not found.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @Kamran No. I switched to the local environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To log into a container, use the following command:

```
kubectl exec -it POD bash
```

Replace `POD` with the name of the pod in which the container is running. This works for pods with a single container. For pods with multiple containers, use the `-c` option to specify the container.

Comment: To install I ran this **gcloud components update kubectl** on my ubuntu. I got this error: **You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.**
I tried to run the command mentioned by you on ssh window opened from the google console, I got this error: **error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused**

Comment: You probably just need to tell gcloud to configure the kubectl command: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations#configuring_kubectl

Comment: When I run that command i get this error **WARNING: Accessing a Container Engine cluster requires the kubernetes commandline
client [kubectl]. To install, run
  $ gcloud components update kubectl

Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for test.
** 
and to install kubectl I get error as in my previous comment.

I think I'll have to start from start. Something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @user3275095, Although you've switched to local environment, I'd still like to send you [this link](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/docker-cli-to-kubectl.html) for your reference. If you've been a docker user, you can find the kubectl equivalent. For example, to list containers running inside a node you can run `docker ps` or `kubectl get po`. kubectl is preinstalled on google cloud shell.

Comment: Regarding the error message that you received while installing the kubectl, please take a look at my answer on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130637/gcloud-component-update-fails/35495298#35495298) for the solution.

Comment: @Kamran Thanks. Hope I find it useful if I use GCE again sometime. :)

Comment: Yes this is the correct command to SSH into a container running in gke

Comment: so if I have multiple containers how does the command look like? Also if I have multiple containers and dont use -c option and run the same command as above which container will I be in?